# How can two beams in the Michelson interferometer come back at the same time?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, geometry, interferometry

I am trying to understand this concept from my textbook.

According to the figure below, the time difference between the two paths $\Delta t=0$.[image]

But why is this the case? Looking at the picture, the distance travelled in path B-C is $$\sqrt{(ut)^{2}+L^{2}}$$ where $u$ is the speed of the moving plate and $t$ is time.

This distance should be longer than $L$ of path B-E.

So, if the speed of light is the same, shouldn't B-C path takes longer to travel?

Comment: I’m a little unclear about which two paths we’re talking about.

Comment: The exact arrival times don't matter, because in the experiment we are supposed to have continuous beams of light in both paths. What matters are the phase shifts of the two beams.

Comment: The distance from B to C is L. The distance from B to C’ is longer than L. Are you sure you are not mixing up C and C’ ?

Comment: It's worth noting that the relevant paths that are actually measured by the experiment are not the legs B-C' and B-E', it is the full trips B-C'-B' and B-E'-B'. It measures a *round trip*. That is crucial to the interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Steve notes in the comment to the OP, the full round-trip paths have to be considered.

With a Newtonian/Galilean analysis, 
the longitudinal round-trip B-E'-B' takes **longer**
 than the transverse round-trip B-C'-B'.
That's why they expected a time difference in the round-trips, which depends on the velocity. Rather than measure a tiny time-difference, this optical device used a phase-difference instead.

But that's not the result that was obtained in the experiment.
The observed time difference is zero.

(From on my comments at https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/michelson-and-morley-in-a-space-time-diagram-cant-make-it-work.1010417/ )

The signal along the longitudinal arm takes too long (compared to that of the transverse arm) to return to the moving source. The longitudinal arm is too far away for the receptions to coincide.

To have the reception events coincide (as suggested by the results of the experiment),
**length contraction** of the longitudinal arm is needed.

Here's a video of mine, using a spacetime diagram of the Michelson Morley apparatus,
suggesting that length contraction is needed
https://youtu.be/AXx3CB80rAk
[image: robphy-VisualizingProperTime-LengthContraction]

Here's my interactive visualization
Relativity-LightClock-MichelsonMorley-2018 (robphy)
https://www.geogebra.org/m/XFXzXGTq
(The image shows the case without length contraction.)
[image: robphy-MichelsonMorley-geogebra]

Here is an old paper of mine, where I work out some of the geometry
[already treated in typical textbooks] on a spacetime diagram
"Visualizing proper-time in Special Relativity"
https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0505134

Comment: Thank you, I have a quick follow up question. Even if the two beams are in phase with each other, how can we conclude the time difference is zero? As long as the path difference is an integer number of wavelength, the two beams would be in phase, no?

Comment: @SirouEwei One can re-orient (rotate) the apparatus. Using 90 degrees, for example, effectively swaps which arm is longitudinal and which is transverse.